# How to make this toggle effect possible?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, xhtml

default condition

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/330969/1104593215-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/330969/1104593215-My-Desktop.png)

After clicking on Sitemap link

How to write HTML to get footer links after the sitemap tree upon clicking on Sitemap link?

[alt text http://shup.com/Shup/330973/110459357-My-Desktop.png](http://shup.com/Shup/330973/110459357-My-Desktop.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Jquery [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) and [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) are your friends. Or, an even easier solution is to use [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)!

```
$('#show_hide').click(function(){
  $("#links").toggle();
  return false;
});
```

Comment: In what respect? Styling? Or simply constructing the html?

Comment: when user will click on sitamap button then link of footer should shift under the sitemap tree

Comment: Create 2 columns. In the right hand one is the sitemap link, in the left hand one is the sitemap (div) and the footer links (p tag). Give the columns fixed widths and float each one left or right. Let me know if that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Style the links and the sitemap in a layout that you desire, then add the following JavaScript (tag the sitemap with id #sitemap and the link with id #smLink):

```
function toggleSitemap() {
  var sitemap = document.getElementById('sitemap'),
      smLink  = document.getElementById('smLink');
  smLink.innerHTML = (smLink.innerHTML == 'Sitemap -') ? 'Sitemap +' : 'Sitemap -';
  sitemap.style.display = (smLink.innerHTML == 'Sitemap -') ? 'block' : 'none';
}
document.getElementById('smLink').addEventListener('click', toggleSitemap, false);
```

Comment: but after clicking i need footer link at bottom of sitemap.

Comment: Like I said, use CSS to lay out the elements as you wish; that's the JavaScript code to handle the actual show/hideing.